# unzip python package in kubernetes pod

Tags: python-3.x, kubernetes, containers

How Do I unzip a python package in kubernetes pod which is sitting in BitBucket.

1. How dowe package the bitbucket directory?
2. How do we unpack the bitbucket directory in kubernetes pod?
3. What is the best way to pass around input for python script?
4. How to let python script load the input data from a specific location?
5. Once we unpack the bitbucket directory, how do we upload it to private artifactory? and how do we refer that artifacts repo from our service for unpacking the directory?

Answer (score 0):

Too many questions.  Meta answer: google these things and read up on it

On your specifics:

1. See https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/
2. With git?
3. It depends.  In Kubernetes, passing in Environment vars is nicely handled from config maps
4. It depends what you mean by location and what you mean by input data
5. There is some on this in the packaging docs above

Comment: 1. I got the answer
2. Yes with Git-bitbucket- The code is in bitbucket- it should be zipped and be accessed from kubernetes pod
3. Input data - probably a text file
4. Main issue - how to access this bitbucket repo as a zip in kube pod and run the application. Unable to find definitive answers

Comment: I suggest you write another question describing exactly what you want to do (and why) with the bitbucket repo in a kube pod.  I can't really tell you what to do as it's not clear  to me what you are trying to achieve.  People use bitbucket hosted python code all the time, it works fine...